# How to solve image loading problem in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I'm making a mock of data and rendering it using map. But my images take a long time to load and the component is a little slow.

I've already tried using Image component from Nextjs, but it gives an error because it only accepts a string in the src and I'm passing an array of images.

Code:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Thanos',
        image: '/images/thanos.png'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jhon Wick',
        image: '/images/jhon.png'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Spider-Man',
        image: '/images/spider.png'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Doctor Strange',
        image: '/images/strange.png'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Batman',
        image: '/images/batman.png'
    }
]

export function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((d) => (
                <div key={d.id}>
                    <img src={d.image} alt="Image" />
                    <p>{d.name}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the size of those images?
Try to tiny those images and check out if this will help you out

This is one service that can help you

https://tinypng.com/

About the next image component, how have you tried to use it? You shouldn't pass the whole array of images, you must use it as same you did as the HTML img tag, but pay attention to width and height props.
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Another thing, check out if your images are in the public folder

Comment: Compressing the image definitely helped me, thanks!